# Optimising the processing of a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples. I need to process the 0th item in each tuple which is a string. This string should end up as a list of integers split on the hyphen. However, to deal with negative numbers, I have had to write some extra stuff beyond a simple .split('-') method. The problem cases are if the string starts with a '-' (then the first number is a negative number) and if there are two hyphens in a row (--) then there must be a hyphen separating a negative number.

This takes a long time to load (minutes), I guess because of the while loop which iterates through things.

I cannot see another way of achieving this operation more quickly. Any suggestions?

```
chunks_ord_by_freq = [('1', 166),('2', 92), ('1-1', 72), ('3', 51), ('1-2', 35), ('2-1', 35), ('-1', 33), ('1-1-1', 31), ('-2', 29), ('-3', 26), ('2-2', 22), ('4', 19),
 ('-4', 19), ('-5', 19), ('3-1', 18), ('1-3', 18), ('1-1-2', 17), ('2-1-1', 17), ('11', 17), ('13', 17), ('1-2-1', 14),
 ('1-1-1-1', 12), ('2-2-1', 11), ('10', 11), ('1-2-2', 10), ('2-3', 9), ('1-1-3', 9), ('1-2-1-1', 9), ('2-1-1-1', 9), ('9', 9), ('3-2', 8),
 ('3-1-1', 8), ('1-2-2-1', 8),('1-1-1-2', 8), ('1-1-2-1', 8), ('8', 8),('1-3-1', 7), ('2-1-2', 7), ('1-2-1-1-1', 7), ('7', 7),('13--3', 7)]

def hyphen_str_to_list(tuples_list):
    res = []

    for tup in tuples_list:
        string = tup[0]

        # for these strange cases, do this
        if string[0] == '-' or "--" in string:

            pro = []

            while len(string) > 0:

                first_digit = str()
                if len(string) == 1: # then there is only a single digit and nothing else
                        first_digit = string
                        string = ''
                elif len(string) == 2: 
                    if string[0] == '-': # then there is only a single digit negative number
                        first_digit = string[0:1]
                        string = ''

                elif string[0] != '-' and string[1] != '-': # then there is only a double digit number and nothing else
                    first_digit = string[0:1]
                    string = ''

                else: # then there is more than one digit in the list

                    if string[0] == '-': # then the first digit is a negative number

                        if string[2] == '-': # then single digit negative number
                            first_digit = string[0:1]
                            string = string[3:]
                        else: # then it's a double digit negative number
                            first_digit = string[0:2]
                            string = string[4:]

                    else: # then the first digit is a positive number
                        if string[1] == '-': # then single digit positive number
                            first_digit = string[0]
                            string = string[2:]
                        else: # then it's a double digit positive number
                            first_digit = string[0:1]
                            string = string[3:]

                    pro.append(first_digit)

        else:
            pro = string.split('-')

    pro = list(map(int, pro)) 
    res.append(pro)
    return(res)




hyphen_str_to_list(chunks_ord_by_freq)
```

Comment: Is this the complete list of tuples? How long is the list for the process to take minutes?

Comment: Full list is length 688. And it will be longer eventually too (10s of thousands)

Comment: Don't you just want to split on only the dashes that are immediately preceded by digits? Use regex, `r"(?<=\d)-"`.

Comment: I am uncomfortable with regex. Could you give me a more complete answer?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, https://regex101.com/r/gDG8Se/1/

Comment: Alternatively, fix this upstream, so that the delimiter isn't a character that also appears in the values.

Comment: Thanks, that was the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of a lot of that logic by using a regex split.

```py
import re

def string_ints_to_list(tupleList):
    parsedList = []
    for string, freq in tupleList:
        parsedList.append((list(map(int,re.split(r"(?<=\d)-",string))), freq))

    return parsedList
```